# Angular 7 send two parameters or more to ASP.NET server

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm new to Angular, I'm using Angular 7 as client side and ASP.NET as server side.

I want to pass more than 2 parameters. I've succeeded to send one parameter.

Here's my Angular service method that sends 2 parameters:

```
validate_user(user : Users, active: boolean): Observable<UsersError> {
    console.log(user);

    return this.http.post<UsersError>(this.users, user, active);
}
```

Here's my ASP.NET post method:

```
public UsersError Post([FromBody] sp_GetUsers_Result user, bool active)
{
        UsersError u = new UsersError
        {
            UserName = "Username Invalid",
            Password = "Password Invalid"
        };

        return u;
}
```

I know I can wrap the parameters into an object and send it as one, but I want to know is there a way to do it with two or more parameters (objects).

I tried to use `HttpParams` with various combinations, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter in `.post` is `httpOptions` :

Example:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

So you'd need to change this line :

```
return this.http.post<UsersError>(this.users, user, active);
```

`active` should be send as param

Regarding asp.net : submitting/posting must match an object in the controller.

Asp.net wil take the body params and will try to match them into the controller argument (fromBody). You can't mix it with another argument(*).

In short , you'd have to add `active` to a new model in server.

`*` You can  , but it will require some other hacks - like I've built: https://github.com/RoyiNamir/SimplePostVariableParameterBindingExtended

Comment: so the only way to send data is with one object that contains all data?

Comment: The only `built-in` way. yes. AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

```
BundleTypeAttributeView(users: string, Active: boolean, ): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('users', users).set("Active", Active);
    return this.http.get<any>(this.endPoint + 'bundleTypeAttributes', { params });
}
```